# Lift's splitting single tags into pairs leads to issues

Tags: html, scala, cross-browser, lift

I'm using [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) for some html-pages of my project. Img tags are inserted by a snippet into the Nivo's div. In all browsers all looks fine - except IE: duplicated images, broken navigation, etc. The cause is that the snippet transforms `<img ... />` into `<img></img>` tag pair. Is there a way not to split single tags into pairs with Scala/Lift during processing?

Comment: I’ve never had this issue with lift. Could you tell us a bit more about your setup?

Comment: Nothing special - installed with Maven, Lift 2.1, Jetty. Snippet construct tags with for loop an such expression: `yield <img /> % Attribute(None, "src", Text(src), Null)`

Comment: I've compared html from different browsers - it seems, that tag splitting is done directly by IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to turn off Lift's IE render feature. In Boot.scala:

```
LiftRules.calcIEMode = () => false
```